# python selenium не находится элемент

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Не находится элемент input и button на этом сайте https://faucet.evmos.org/ Он не в фрейме, поэтому я понятия не имею, что здесь не так. Я пробовал
`driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/input')`
`driver.find_element_by_class_name('sc-bdfBQB ilgFxU form-control')`,
но всё бестолку. Выходит ошибка selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJ8Cm.png)/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/input"}

Comment: chrome  говорит, что xpath к инпуту `//*[@id="root"]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/input` . Но почему бы просто не поискать `//input` ? там он всего один

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался. Не знаю почему, но по нормальному xpath там не ищется.